# Create Relationship Between Two Columns Not Using PK SQL

Tags: sql, linq, database-design, relationships

I have two tables, one named Game and the other GameStats.

Game Design

```
GameId (PK)
GameGuid
MatchDate
TeamZeroScore
TeamOneScore
Active
```

GameStats Design

```
GameStatsId (PK)
GameGuid
TeamId
Name
Kills
Deaths
Assists
Active
```

A game can have many game stats. So my question is is there any way to set up a relationship between Game and Gamestats using the GameGuid field even though they are not primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but I wouldn't recommend it.  In general, you can set up a foreign key relationship to another table using either a primary key or unique key (where key can actually consist of multiple columns).

However, you don't want to store redundant data in tables.  So, if `GameId` is the primary key for `Game`, then the second table should be:

```
GameStatsId (PK)
GameId references Game(GameId)
TeamId
Name
Kills
Deaths
Assists
Active
```

You can look up the `GameGuid` by doing a join.

On the other hand, if you want to use `GameGuid` as the primary key, then use that and remove `GameId`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I think I will go with adding GameId to the GameStats table. But this introduces the problem of existing data, I will need to go through all the Gamestats data and add the matching game id through the same gameguid